# Tooltip does not work in meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my sample code:

https://github.com/xois/meteortooltip

header.html

```
<li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="test title" href="#">test</a></li>
```

header.js

```
Template.header.rendered = function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({palacement: 'bottom'});
};
```

packages

```
meteor-platform
twbs:bootstrap
iron:router
```

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use

    .rendered = function(){};

because it was deprecated. Instead use .onRendered(function(){});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `tooltip` call ("palacement"):

```
Template.header.rendered = function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({placement: 'bottom'});
};
```